# extract strings from a service response and group values basis on keys from that response

Tags: python, linux, perl, awk, sed

I have a service `(http://localhost:8080/tester)` that gives me below response when I call it. I have shorten the format to make it clear.

```
modified=false
ver=10
PATH=/doc/path/abc
    Servers:3
    pri:{0=1, 1=2, 2=3, 3=4, 4=5, 5=6, 6=7, 7=8, 8=1, 9=2, 10=3, 11=4, 12=5, 13=6, 14=7, 15=8, 17=2, 16=1, 19=4, 18=3, 21=6, 20=5, 23=8, 22=7, 25=2, 24=1, 27=4, 26=3, 29=6, 28=5, 31=8, 30=7, 34=3, 35=4, 32=1, 33=2, 38=7, 39=8, 36=5, 37=6, 42=3, 43=4, 40=1}
    sec:{0=2, 1=3, 2=4, 3=5, 4=6, 5=7, 6=8, 7=1, 8=3, 9=4, 10=5}
PATH=/doc/path/pqr
    Servers:3
    pri:{0=1, 1=2, 2=3, 3=4, 4=5, 5=6, 6=7, 7=8, 8=1, 9=2, 10=3, 11=4, 12=5, 13=6, 14=7, 15=8, 17=2, 16=1, 19=4, 18=3, 21=6, 20=5, 23=8, 22=7, 25=2, 24=1, 27=4, 26=3, 29=6, 28=5, 31=8, 30=7, 34=3, 35=4, 32=1, 33=2, 38=7, 39=8, 36=5, 37=6, 42=3, 43=4, 40=1}
    sec:{0=2, 1=3, 2=4, 3=5, 4=6, 5=7, 6=8, 7=1, 8=3, 9=4, 10=5}
```

I need to read this response and extract value of `pri` and `sec` but only for `PATH=/doc/path/abc`. Now format of `pri` and `sec` is like this:

```
{value1=key1, value2=key2, value3=key2, value4=key1}
```

Each unique key can have multiple values both in `pri` and `sec` list. Now I need to read both `pri` and `sec` list and make two files `p.txt` for `pri` list and `s.txt` for `sec` list by grouping values basis on unique key like below:

**p.txt** Here keys and values come from `pri` list.

```
{key1=[value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8], key2=[value9, value10, value11, value12, value13, value14]}
```

**s.txt** Here keys and values come from `sec` list.

```
{key1=[value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8], key2=[value9, value10, value11, value12, value13, value14]}
```

I can't figure out how to extract `pri` and `sec` value just for `PATH=/doc/path/abc` and make corresponding files `p.txt` and `s.txt` by grouping values for each unique key just like in the above format.

```
DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://localhost:8080/tester);
echo $DATA
# extract pri and sec here and then group values basis on unique keys 
# and generate files accordingly.
while IFS= read -r $DATA
do
   echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: Yikes. Is Perl or Python an option?

Comment: Yeah perl or python are an option as well. It's gonna be hard parsing these string and formatting it back via linux for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, my Perl's a bit rusty, but here's something to get you started. It parses the entire data structure, then pulls off the parts given on the command line. I don't know what version of Perl you're working with, or if you have the ability to install modules, so I kept it as bare-bones as possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

unless (@ARGV >= 2) {
  die "USAGE: $0 path key=/path/to/key.txt ..\n";
}

our $WANTED_PATH = $ARGV[0];
our %WANTED_KEYS = map split(/=/, $_, 2), @ARGV[1..$#ARGV];

my $data = parse(*STDIN)->{PATH}{$WANTED_PATH}
  or die "FATAL: Path <$WANTED_PATH> not found\n";

while (my ($key, $file) = each %WANTED_KEYS) {
  unless (exists $data->{$key}) {
    warn "Key <$key> not found\n";

    next;
  }

  write_file($file, $data->{$key});

  print "Wrote key <$key> to file <$file>\n";
}

sub parse {
  my ($fh, $wanted) = @_;

  # contains the current subsection of the data being parsed
  my $current_path;

  my %data = (PATH => {});
  while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;

    next unless $line =~ /\S/;

    if ($line =~ s/^\s+//) {
      if ($current_path) {
        my ($key, $value) = split /\s*:\s*/, $line, 2;

        if (exists $WANTED_KEYS{$key}) {
          $value = parse_pairs($value);
        }

        $data{PATH}{$current_path}{$key} = $value;
      }
    }
    else {
      my ($key, $value) = split /\s*=\s*/, $line, 2;

      if ($key eq 'PATH') {
        $data{$key}{$current_path = $value} = {};
      }
      else {
        $data{$key} = $value;
      }
    }
  }

  return \%data;
}

sub parse_pairs {
  my ($pairs) = @_;

  my %data;
  while ($pairs =~ /(\d+)\s*=\s*(\d+)/g) {
    push @{ $data{$2} ||= [] }, $1;
  }

  return \%data;
}

sub write_file {
  my ($file, $data) = @_;

  open(my $fh, '>', $file)
    or die "FATAL: Unable to open file <$file> for writing: $!\n";

  print {$fh} '{';
  print {$fh} join ', ',
    map sprintf('%s=[%s]', $_, join(', ', sort @{ $data->{$_} })),
    sort keys %$data;
  print {$fh} '}';

  close($fh);
}
```

Use it like so:

```
wget -O- -q -t1 http://localhost:8080/tester |
  ./tester.pl /doc/path/abc pri=p.txt sec=s.txt
```

Comment: yeah its complaining about this module `LWP::Simple module`. checking on how I can install this module on ubuntu 16. let me know if you know the steps

Comment: @user5447339 `apt-get install libwww-perl` should do the trick. I can also modify it to accept the output of `wget` on the input. Let me know if you'd prefer that.

Comment: yeah wget will be great I think

Comment: @user5447339 Updated!

Comment: I am getting this error: `Can't use string ("{0=2, 1=3, 2=4, 3=5, 4=6, 5=7, 6"...) as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ./tester.pl line 83.` I think this is the line `    map sprintf('%s=[%s]', $_, join(', ', sort @{ $data->{$_} })),`